# Error in creating graph from DiagrammeR package

Tags: r, diagrammer

I am trying to create a node-link diagram in R using the `DiagrammeR` package from the below code:

```
library(DiagrammeR)

nodes <- create_nodes(nodes = 1:7, type = "number")

edges <- create_edges(from = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3),
                        to = c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7),
                       rel = "leading to")

graph <- create_graph(nodes_df = nodes, 
                      edges_df = edges, 
                      graph_attrs = "layout = dot", 
                      node_attrs = "fontname = Helvetica", 
                      edge_attrs = "color = gray20") 

# View the graph
render_graph(graph)
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error in create_nodes(nodes = 1:7, type = "number") : 
  could not find function "create_nodes"
```

Are there any alternative ways to create a diagram like  this in R:

[image: node-link diagram]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions `create_nodes` and `create_edges` were deprecated some time ago. Here's some code that uses the replacements.

```
library(DiagrammeR)

nodes <- create_node_df(n=7, type = "number")

edges <- create_edge_df(from = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3),
                                        to = c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7),
                                        rel = "leading to")

graph <- create_graph(nodes_df = nodes, edges_df = edges)

render_graph(graph)
```

[image]